# Intuition for $\int_X g\,d\phi = \int_X gf\,d\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there any intuition for the following result?

**Theorem**: Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ be measurable. Let $\phi$ be the measure defined by $\phi(E) = \int_E f \,d\mu$ for each $E \in \mathcal{A}$. Then for each measurable $g: X \to [0,\infty]$, we have $$\int_X g\,d\phi = \int_X gf\,d\mu.$$

Reference: Theorem 1.29 of Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*

Comment: I like to go back to Riemann integration whenever I want some intuition. How about considering $$\phi = \int f(t) dt$$
which gives $$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = f(t)$$
If we take this for granted, it's just $d\phi = f(t) dt$. Rudin mentions that this is commonly stated in shorthand notation as $d\phi = f d\mu$, which is kind of similar to what you'd see in Riemann integration. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: if you want to think physically then you can think of $f$ as representing some mass density, $\mu$ being Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^3$. So, the equation is saying that "to integrate wrt mass is the same as multiplying by density and then integrating wrt volume". This should be very reasonable and easy to physically interpret when $f$ is a simple function.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to seek intuition in the finite, discrete case. Suppose, for simplicity, that $X=\{1,2,\dots ,n\}$ and $\mu$ is the counting measure. Pick any set of positive numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$, Let $f:X\to [0,\infty)$ be defined by $f(i)=a_i$, and for $E\subset X$ put
$$\phi(E)=\sum_{i\in E}a_i=\int_Ef\,d\mu$$
Let $g$ be any function defined on $X$, assuming non-negative values, i.e. $g:X\to [0,\infty)$ is a measurable function. Then
$$\int_X g\,d\phi=\sum_{i=1}^na_ig(i)=\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)g(i)=\int_Xgf\,d\mu$$

The general case is the "continuous" version of this.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [epsilon-emperor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/425395/epsilon-emperor)'s comment, intiutively you can think it as $ d\phi = f d\mu $. Thus,
$$ d\phi = f d\mu \quad \implies \quad g d\phi = fg d\mu \quad \implies \quad \int_X g d\phi = \int_X fg d\mu $$

The above is just a formal calculation, a priori. But actually it can be justified rigorously using the notion of **Radon-Nikodym derivative**.

A non-negative function $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ is said to be a **Radon-Nikodym derivative of a measure $\phi$ with respect to another measure $\mu$** if for any measurable set $E$, we have

$$ \phi(E) = \int_E f d\mu $$

Any two functions that satisfy this conditions are equal $\mu$-almost everywhere and we can denote it as

$$ \frac{d\phi}{d\mu} = f \quad \mu\text{-a.e.}
\quad \text{or} \quad d\phi = f d\mu $$

Now, if $f$ is such a function, then a theorem says that for any measurable function $g$ such that either $g \geq 0$ or $g$ is integrable, we have

$$ \quad \int_X g d\phi = \int_X fg d\mu $$

The proof uses the standard argument of simple approximation, which is a four-step procedure. First, you prove the identity for an indicator function $g = \mathbb{1}_E$. Next, you extend the identity linearly for any simple functions $g$. Then it comes the most important step: approximate $g \geq 0$ by an increasing sequence of simple functions and use monotone convergence theorem to prove the identity for any non-negative function $g$. Finally, conclude the result for any integrable function $g$ by splitting $g$ into positive and negative parts, and into real and imaginary parts in case $g$ is complex-valued.

In fact, doing the routine proof procedure described above would also give you some intuition of why the identity is true, so you should try to do it once. I leave it as an exercise.